# Why truffle deploy fail with address value=0 after I upgrade to version 5.0.5?

Tags: solidity, truffle, solc

I have a truffle `2_deploy_contracts.js` something like this :

```
const sample = artifacts.require('./Sample.sol');

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer
    .then(()=>deployer.deploy(Sample, 0x0))
};
```

Sample contract require `address` to be passed. This was worked at truffle version `^4.1.14` but after I upgraded truffle version to `Truffle v5.0.5 (core: 5.0.5)`, it fail with this error message below:

```
2_deploy_contracts.js
=====================

   Deploying 'Sample'
   ---------------------------
Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"Sample" -- invalid address (arg="_address", coderType="address", value=0).
```

Comment: Please share your `Sample` contract (or at least the constructor of this contract).

Comment: If you are trying to pass `0x0` as an `address` to your constructor, why bother passing the parameter at all?

Comment: Facing the same issue. The only difference is that I get my value = undefined